# Get the root of a Rose tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree

Recently I started to learn about Haskell, and am struggling with the following exercise:

```
Write functions root :: Rose a -> a and children :: Rose a -> [Rose a]
that return the value stored at the root of a rose tree, respectively the children of the
root of a rose tree.
```

They gave me the following basic code to start:

```
data Rose a = a :> [Rose a]
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I don't know what (:>) means. I tried to understand it by typing in the ghci

```
Input: :t (:>)
Output: a -> [Rose a] -> Rose a
```

So I think it means that you have an `a` value, which will be used to lookup `Rose a` out of a list and returns `Rose a`, but I'm still confused what to do next.

If I look at the signature of `root :: Rose a -> a`, the function would look like this:

```
root (Rose a) = a
```

And the function of `children :: Rose a -> [Rose a]`:

```
children (Rose a) = (Rose a):[]
```

This is not correct, and I don't how to make it correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The declaration

```
data Rose a = a :> [Rose a]
```

is basically equivalent to

```
data Rose a = Node a [Rose a]
```

In other words, `Node` is a data structure containing a datum and a list of child nodes. But in the definition above, rather than calling it `Node`, it's called `:>`. It's just a made-up name; Haskell allows you to create user-defined operators like this.

If the name `Node` was used, you could write

```
root (Node datum children) = datum
```

Or, more briefly,

```
root (Node a rs) = a
```

Since the name given is actually `:>`, you'd have to write it as

```
root (a :> rs) = a
```

In particular, you seem to be trying to use `Rose`, but that's the *type constructor*, not the *value constructor*. Similarly, you seem to be trying to use the "`:`" operator, but that's for lists, not rose trees.

Hopefully that clears up some things for you.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination!