# Find Root and Root Children of Rose Tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree

I would like to be able to fully answer the question about how to find the root and the the children of a rose tree.
The first part (how to find the root) has been essentially answered already on stackoverflow here

http://bit.ly/1YdoEhh

The rose tree is defined with the following notation

```
data Rose a = a :> [Rose a]
deriving (Eq, Show)
```

and the root can be detected simply as

```
root (a :> rs) = a
```

I would like to have the expression (with the ":>" notation for the Node) of the function to find the children of the root.
Example of expected behavior of this function children

```
children (1 :> [2 :> [], 3 :> []]) = [2 :> [], 3 :> []]
```

Anyone can help me out?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the root of a Rose tree in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726783/get-the-root-of-a-rose-tree-in-haskell)

Comment: In future questions, please don't use URL shorteners, and also add enough information about your problem so that we can answer without looking elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It's just pattern-matching the second argument rather than the first. Given the declaration:

```hs
data Rose x = Rose x [Rose x] deriving (Show, Eq)
```

we can write:

```hs
root :: Rose x -> x
root (Rose x _) = x

children :: Rose x -> [Rose x]
children (Rose _ rs) = rs
```

Or we could save ourselves a bit of trouble by writing this with "record notation" and define those two implicitly as:

```hs
data Rose x = Rose {root :: x, children :: [Rose x]} deriving (Show, Eq)
```

(But don't be fooled! `root` does not have type `x` but type `Rose x -> x` as before, it's just that the `Rose x ->` is considered redundant and not written!)

What if you didn't want a `[Rose x]` but rather just a `[x]`? Then you want to transform each element of the list with the `root` function, which takes the element at the current cell in the rose tree. This "transform every element with a function" function is called `map` for lists or `fmap` in general. So you can write simply `map root (children roseTree)`, if your tree is called `roseTree`, to get a `[x]`. We could write that directly with the function composition operator `.` as:

```hs
childElements :: Rose x -> [x]
childElements = map root . children
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you adapt your answer to the newest version of the post (and notation for the Node)?